Python dict question get() function dumps
I have a Python dict question where I struggle with using the typical tutorials I can find. In my debugger I see the following dict (call it instance_dict in my code)
{
<segment_display.displayScore1>: {'show_43.segment_display_player.displayScore1': True},
<segment_display.displayScore2>: {'show_43.segment_display_player.displayScore2': True},
<segment_display.displayPlayer>: {'show_43.segment_display_player.displayPlayer': True},
<segment_display.displayScore3>: {'show_43.segment_display_player.displayScore3': True},
<segment_display.displayScore4>: {'show_43.segment_display_player.displayScore4': True},
<segment_display.displayBall>: {'show_43.segment_display_player.displayBall': True},
<segment_display.neoSegTopLine>: {},
<segment_display.neoSegBottomLine>: {}
}

Am I reading it correctly that for example <segment_display.displayScore1> is the key, and that in this case the key is an object and not a string?
If that is correct, how do I understand the value {'show_43.segment_display_player.displayScore1': True} is the value another dict object?
Now I run a for loop for a in instance_dict.items():
Now I want to get the value for each item. I thought I can do
instance_dict.get(a) in my for loop to get the value -but that dumps. Of course I could do for a, b in .... But why is my code dumping?

but that dumps what does it mean "dumps"? Code does not "dump". What does it "dump"?

Please show the code that is "dumping" and the exact error messag

But why is my code dumping? If you show us what actually happens, perhaps we could answer.

a is not a key of instance_dict. It's a (key, value) tuple, because .items() returns both keys and values. If you used for a in instance_dict.keys(): then you could use instance_dict.get(a) to get the corresponding value.

You can also just use a[1] to get the value.


and that in this case the key is an object and not a string?

Yes and yes.

is the value another dict object?

Yes.
